# xceed MaskedTextBox Mask Binding to Greater Than symbol

Tags: escaping, maskedtextbox, xceed

Unable to bind simple text mask in xceed MaskedTextBox

```
var state = new MaskedEditableTextField(String.Empty, "State", ">LL", rules);

<xctk:MaskedTextBox Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Mask="{Binding TextMask}"
                            ToolTip="{Binding OriginalValue}"
                            ValueDataType="{x:Type s:String}"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ValidatableEditableTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

binding to other masks that don't have the '`>`' or '`&gt;`' value work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Despite there being a mask character for pushing to upper case, the control also has a 'Case' setting

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            CharacterCasing="{Binding Casing}"
                            Mask="{Binding TextMask}"
                            ToolTip="{Binding OriginalValue}"
                            ValueDataType="{x:Type s:String}"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ValidatableEditableTextBoxStyle}"/>
```